# jsonb[] vs jsonb where json is an array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table, `mytable` where one of the field is as follows:

`myField  JSONB[] NOT NULL`

and let's assume the said jsons are of this form:

`{ "letter":"A", "digit":30}`

What queries should I use to:

- extract an array of the `digit` values?
- extract a json array containing the `digit` values?
- extract an array of the `digit` values where `digit > 20`?
- extract a json array of the `digit` values where `digit > 20`?

How would the above queries change if I stored the data as json where the json was a list?

- Can I still make all the above queries?
- What would be the performance difference?
- When should I choose one over the other?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's create a table that has both a column of type `jsonb[]` called `pg_array` that will store an array JSON objects and a column of type `jsonb` called `json_array` that will store a JSON array of objects:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, pg_array jsonb[], json_array jsonb);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    (1, ARRAY['{"letter":"A", "digit":30}', '{"letter":"B", "digit":31}']::jsonb[], '[{"letter":"A", "digit":30},{"letter":"B", "digit":31}]'),
    (2, ARRAY['{"letter":"X", "digit":40}', '{"letter":"Y", "digit":41}']::jsonb[], '[{"letter":"X", "digit":40},{"letter":"Y", "digit":41}]');
```

The queries for both approaches will look very similar because we'll be working on the individual array elements, meaning we'll have to unnest and aggreate again.

To unnest `pg_array` and get each `jsonb` object:

```sql
SELECT unnest(pg_array);
```

To unnest `json_array` and get each `jsonb` object:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json_array);
```

That's the only difference. Thus, the queries below will look almost identical.

On to your first set of questions:

> extract an array of the digit values?

```
db=# SELECT array_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, unnest(pg_array) x GROUP BY id;
 array_agg
-----------
 {40,41}
 {30,31}
(2 rows)
```

```
db=# SELECT array_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(json_array) x GROUP BY id;
 array_agg
-----------
 {40,41}
 {30,31}
(2 rows)
```

> extract a json array containing the digit values?

```
db=# SELECT jsonb_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, unnest(pg_array) x GROUP BY id;
 jsonb_agg
-----------
 [40, 41]
 [30, 31]
(2 rows)
```

```
db=# SELECT jsonb_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(json_array) x GROUP BY id;
 jsonb_agg
-----------
 [40, 41]
 [30, 31]
(2 rows)
```

> extract an array of the digit values where digit > 20?

(I've used 30 instead of 20 here.)

```
db=# SELECT array_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, unnest(pg_array) x WHERE (x->>'digit')::int > 30 GROUP BY id;
 array_agg
-----------
 {40,41}
 {31}
(2 rows)
```

```
db=# SELECT array_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(json_array) x WHERE (x->>'digit')::int > 30 GROUP BY id;
 array_agg
-----------
 {40,41}
 {31}
(2 rows)
```

> extract a json array of the digit values where digit > 20?

(I've used 30 instead of 20 here.)

```
db=# SELECT jsonb_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, unnest(pg_array) x WHERE (x->>'digit')::int > 30 GROUP BY id;
 jsonb_agg
-----------
 [40, 41]
 [31]
(2 rows)
```

```
db=# SELECT jsonb_agg((x->>'digit')::int) FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(json_array) x WHERE (x->>'digit')::int > 30 GROUP BY id;
 jsonb_agg
-----------
 [40, 41]
 [31]
(2 rows)
```

For your second set of questions:

> Can I still make all the above queries?

As seen above, yes.

> What would be the performance difference?

That boils down to the performance difference of `unnest` and `jsonb_array_elements`. Let's compare that with a single row that contains an array with 1,000,000 JSON objects:

```sql
TRUNCATE mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT 1, array_agg(o), jsonb_agg(o)
FROM (SELECT jsonb_build_object('letter', 'A', 'digit', i) o FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) i) x;
```

```
phil=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT unnest(pg_array) FROM mytable;
                                                QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..35.88 rows=5000 width=32) (actual time=33.357..120.393 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..10.50 rows=50 width=626) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.050 ms
 Execution time: 175.670 ms
(4 rows)

phil=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT jsonb_array_elements(json_array) FROM mytable;
                                                QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..35.88 rows=5000 width=32) (actual time=257.313..399.883 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..10.50 rows=50 width=721) (actual time=0.010..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.047 ms
 Execution time: 455.275 ms
(4 rows)
```

From this it looks like `unnest` is around 2.5 times faster than `jsonb_array_elements`.

> When should I choose one over the other?

I assume that your dataset isn't big enough for the difference in performance between `unnest` and `jsonb_array_elements` to play a role. Thus, I'd just choose what makes more sense in terms of the data. I'd tend to go with `jsonb[]` as it more clearly communicates that you'll have an array of json objects.